# PySide make QDialog appear in main window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I've created an app which has an main window and the possibility to open an dialog (question, error and so on). I'm not using `QMessageBox.warning()` or `QMessageBox.question()` and so on because I wanted to customize the dialogs a bit.

But every time I open a new Dialog, in the Windows task bar (I'm working on Windows 10) a new 'tab' is opened, which is a little bit annoying.

[image]

My code (shortened):

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class MessageBox:
    def __init__(self, title, message):
        msg = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        flags = QtCore.Qt.Dialog
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint
        msg.setWindowFlags(flags)
        msg.setWindowTitle(title)
        msg.setText(message)
        msg.exec_()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.show()

        MessageBox("Title", "My message here")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Note:** Normally, the dialog is called from an menu or button.

**Question:** How can I make the dialog appear in the main window without creating a new 'task bar tab'?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9043996/4941927, could help you

Comment: @Milor123 Thanks, I'm doing it like this already. The button is connected using `self.mybutton.clicked.connect(self.myfunc)`. In `myfunc`, the dialog is called using `MessageBox("Title", "My message here")`. Any ideas?

Comment: Besides the fact that it doesn't make much sense to create a class and just do all the job in the constructor (either you inherit to extend the class, or you just create a function?), you should set correctly the parent of the new dialog to the main dialog to have the focus and the window grouping working correctly.

Comment: @MatteoItalia As I wrote, in my real code the dialog is called from another function. I tried setting the parent some time ago, but that doesn't worked. Can you tell me how to set the parent of a `QDialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was quite simple: Passing an reference of `QMainWindow` to the constructor of `QDialog` will do the job, e.g:

```
class MessageBox(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, title, message, icon="info"):
        super(MessageBox, self).__init__(parent)
        ...
```

and then calling the dialog from an class that inherits from `QMainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        #connect button with function, e.g.:
        mybutton.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)

   def open_dialog(self):
       MessageBox(self)
```

Maybe this helps anyone!

Comment: Why did you copy my answer?

Answer (score -1):

If you set the parent of the `QDialog` to the window, it will only show as one item on the task bar.  This is generally the first argument to `QMessageBox`.

```
class MessageBox:
    def __init__(self, parent, title, message):
        msg = QtGui.QMessageBox(parent)
```

Also, if you really want to create a custom dialog, you might as well just subclass from `QDialog`.