# QFileDialog always opens behind main window

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to open a file in my PySide2 application, but the file dialog always opens below the main window and appears as another application in the launcher. The application's name is "Portal".

I see [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36350236/4794) where the solution is to pass the main window as the first parameter to `getOpenFileName()`, but that doesn't work for me.

Here's a simple demonstration of the problem:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QFileDialog, QApplication


class DemoButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    def on_click(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Open a text file.",
            filter='Text file (*.txt)')
        print(file_name)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = DemoButton("Hello World")
    button.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()


main()
```

I thought maybe the parent had to be a `QMainWindow`, so I tried that:

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        # layout initialize
        g_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        main_widget.setLayout(g_layout)

        # Add Widgets
        self.exec_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Execute')
        self.exec_btn.clicked.connect(self.find_file)

        # global layout setting
        g_layout.addLayout(layout)
        g_layout.addWidget(self.exec_btn)

    def find_file(self):
        file_name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Open a text file.",
            filter='Text file (*.txt)')
        print(file_name)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()


main()
```

The file dialog behaved exactly the same.

I'm using PySide2 5.12.2, Python 3.6.7, and running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you describe on my arch linux system. The documented behaviour is that it should produce a modal dialog centred on the parent, and that is exactly what I get. You could try adding `options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog` to see if that changes anything. (PS: I wonder whether the problem is somehow caused by [xdg-desktop-portal](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal). Do you have that installed on your system?).

Comment: I had the same issue. Using a platform.system() check so that on windows I still get the native dialog

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to ekhumoro's comment, I learned that I can tell PySide2 not to use the native file dialog.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QFileDialog, QApplication


class DemoButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    def on_click(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            "Open a text file.",
            filter='Text file (*.txt)',
            options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        print(file_name)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = DemoButton("Hello World")
    button.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()


main()
```

That fixes the behaviour by bringing the file dialog to the front, but I think the native file dialog looks better. Hopefully, there's another option that can make the native file dialog work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  The issue is in part the default windows behavior, which does not allow applications to steal focus.  I was able to solve it by using an external context handler which sets the window focus. This uses the **NativeWindow** method.  This was tested on **Windows 11** with Python 3.10.6, PySide6:

Window context handler is needed to bring the **QFileDialog** forward:

```
import os
import re
import win32gui
import win32com.client 
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication
from PySide6 import QtCore

class WindowMgr:
    """ Encapsulates calls to the winapi for window management
        Forces context window to take focus
        Based on: 
         - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090464/python-window-activation
         - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295337/win32gui-setactivewindow-error-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found
    """

    def __init__ (self):
        self._handle = None

    def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
        """find a window by its class_name"""
        self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)
        return self

    def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
        """Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows"""
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
            self._handle = hwnd

    def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        """find a window whose title matches the wildcard regex"""
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)
        return self

    def set_foreground(self):
        """put the window in the foreground"""
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shell.SendKeys('%')  # left shift key sent, this shifts focus from current window
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)
```

Next, the file dialog is set using the class-based implementation (not the stand-alone shortcut):

```
def file_open_save_dialog(
    def_dir: str = ".", 
    title: str = "Open file", 
    filter: str = "file (*.*)", 
    mode: str = 'open'
) -> str:
    if (def_dir is None) or (def_dir == '.'):
        def_dir = os.getcwd()

    app = QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QApplication([def_dir])

    file_dialog = QFileDialog()
    if mode == 'open':
        file_dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptMode.AcceptOpen)
    elif mode == 'save':
        file_dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptMode.AcceptSave)
    elif mode == 'folder':
        file_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.FileMode.Directory)
    else:
        raise NameError(f"Invalid option given to FileDialog mode: {mode}")

    file_dialog.setNameFilter(filter)
    file_dialog.setDirectory(def_dir)
    file_dialog.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModality.ApplicationModal)
    file_dialog.setWindowTitle(title)
    file_dialog.show()
    WindowMgr().find_window_wildcard(title).set_foreground() # <- from above

    if file_dialog.exec():
        filenames = file_dialog.selectedFiles()
        return filenames[0]
    else:
        return ''
```

## Example use:

### File Open:

```
myopenfile = file_open_save_dialog(def_dir="C:\Temp", title="Select file Foo", filter="Text (*.txt)", mode='open')
```

### File Save:

```
mysavefile = file_open_save_dialog(def_dir="C:\Temp", title="Save to file", filter="Text (*.txt)", mode='save')
```

### Folder select:

```
myfolder = file_open_save_dialog(def_dir="C:\Temp", title="Select Folder", filter="*", mode='folder')
```

These are blocking functions.  Use threading if you need your UI to remain active during the selection process.